# Can I write file on SD Card

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

With the new SDK 8.1 of Windows Phone is there a way to write file on SD Card ? Before we could only read. I have an idea to save file from my app on SD Card and this can be interesting for the Lumia 520 who have few memory.

Answer (score 4):

More information about [Data and Files you will find in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx). And as [written here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx):

> What you can access
>
> Your app can only read and write files of file types that the app has registered to handle in the app manifest file.
>
> Your app can also create and manage folders.

So if you had declared `File Type Association` - there shouldn't be a problem to write/read files.

Note also that your App can be installed on SD Card, then all its files will be located there.

Comment: the application can determine if it is installed on the SD card?

Comment: @TossNet The user decides where the App is being installed (there is an otion in phone settings). In package manifest you may declare that the user won't be able to install on SD. I think it is a must for an App that it can be installed on phone - not every phone has SD card.