# WP8 development: how to backup a local file (SQLite database) without a webservice?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card, database-backups

I need to give the user the option to copy the current state of a local SQLite database created by my WP8 app. I don't have a webservice where the user could upload this database to.

Apparently Microsoft doesn't allow WP8 apps to write to the device's SD card. I then thought about sending the database by email as an attachment, but it also doesn't seem possible.

Any other suggestions? If anybody without a webservice have ever been to this situation: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is a no go if you're using the built in EmailTask.  It will not let you attach a file, plus it is not a silent operation.  See here: [EmailComposeTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704772/windows-phone-sdk-send-email-with-xna-game-engine/26705723#26705723)

You **can write** to the SD CARD -- you just need to setup your application permissions correctly.

See here for more information: [Can I write file on SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296804/can-i-write-file-on-sd-card).  You need to setup the capabilities in your manifest file as well as registers the files extension that you want to read/write before you can do anything on the SD Card.

---

Another option is have them write to their OneDrive account, a lot of popular apps have this option (like the Mic Recorder app).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your help, really appreciated!! I was quite frustrated as I was reading in some places that WinPhone doesn't allow the apps to write to the SD Card for "security reasons". I'll have a look in your links as soon as I can and will come back to give a feeback. Thank you very much again, I'm happy now that you gave me a hope :)

Comment: I have chosen to write the file to OneDrive, it was quite simple in the end. Thanks!